# Im getting an fatal error during executenonquery mysql.dll and empty file path is not legal

Tags: c#, mysql, database, image, mysql-workbench

Hello im trying to save all datas in my database including the image. 
Datatype of my image is longblob am i doing wrong with my codes ? pardon me im just a beginner i hope someone will be able to help me thank you.

```
try {
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root;password=admin; database=dbstudents;";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            //Images Conversion : Datatype in my database is LONGBLOB
            byte[] img = null;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);


            // this is a sample query for update statement and update 
            string Query = "UPDATE tblstudent RIGHT JOIN tbltransact  ON tblstudent.StudentID = tbltransact.EnrolleeID SET FirstName=@firstName , LastName=@lastName , MiddleName=@middleName ,ContactNo=@contactNo ,Address=@address ,Age=@age ,Guardian=@guardian,studentPic=@studentPic,PendingBalance=@pendingBalance, WHERE StudentID=@studentID";
            MySqlCommand cin = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
            myConn.Open();
            if (cin.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", int.Parse(search.Text));
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstname.Text);
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastname.Text);
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", middlename.Text);
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNo", ContactNum.Text);
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text);
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", int.Parse(age.Text));
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guardian", guardian.Text);
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentPic", img );
                cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pendingBalance", int.Parse(Balance.Text));
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

thats all that i made and also here is my database

[image: database]

Comment: pardon me for bad coding , i also have been in trouble of retrieving image longblob it will be a big help if anyone could provide me help

Comment: i just tried that i have my original code which works but its too complicated

Comment: Please include in the question the exact error and where it occurs

Comment: Make sure the field names in c# exactly match the database field names including lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: @StephenKennedy its in the title sir ,and it occurs in my parametrs execute non query

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your parameters *after* executing the command. That can never work. At the moment you call `ExecuteNonQuery()`, none of the parameters are filled in yet.

You're also leaving a file stream open. Use `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` to avoid having to handle streams manually for reading a full file's contents.

```
try
{
    String myConnection = "datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root;password=admin; database=dbstudents;";
    //Images Conversion : Datatype in my database is LONGBLOB
    Byte[] img = File.ReadAllbytes(imgLoc);

    // this is a sample query for update statement and update 
    String Query = "UPDATE tblstudent RIGHT JOIN tbltransact  ON tblstudent.StudentID = tbltransact.EnrolleeID SET FirstName=@firstName , LastName=@lastName , MiddleName=@middleName ,ContactNo=@contactNo ,Address=@address ,Age=@age ,Guardian=@guardian,studentPic=@studentPic,PendingBalance=@pendingBalance, WHERE StudentID=@studentID";

    MySqlCommand cin = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
    using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
    {
        myConn.Open();
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", Int32.Parse(search.Text));
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstname.Text);
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastname.Text);
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", middlename.Text);
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNo", ContactNum.Text);
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text);
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", Int32.Parse(age.Text));
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guardian", guardian.Text);
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentPic", img );
        cin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pendingBalance", Int32.Parse(Balance.Text));
        if (cin.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
        {
            // Handle query failure here
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("No patient found to update for ID {0}", search.Text));
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```